# ReactJs conditional rendering not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call the onLogin() function from a child called Login. This function will set the state based on which the conditional rendering is done.

The problem is that Home is not getting rendered after setState is called. In fact the function getView() is not getting called after calling setState(), although the view is updated after i refresh the page.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLogin.bind(this);
    this.state = {userLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem(USER_NAME)};
  }

  onLogin() {
    this.setState({userLoggedIn: true});
  }

  getView() {
    return this.state.userLoggedIn ? <Home /> :  <Login onLogin={this.onLogin} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <span>
          {this.getView()}
        </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try 'this.onLogin.bind(this)' to setup the  caller

Comment: you might just be missing a bind in the constructor for the `getView` method. if not, you'll need to provide the code of the Login component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.bind(this)` where you pass the prop to Login component like this:

```
<Login onLogin={this.onLogin.bind(this)} />
```

and you can delete the line after `super(props);`
Here is a link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-chaum-5l8k6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks friend, the issue is resolved. It works as expected after i made changes. Previously `this` inside the `onLogin` function refers to the child object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have bound `getView` method like you did for `onLogin`. To avoid binding issues maybe just use arrow functions like so

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {userLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem(USER_NAME)};
  }

  const onLogin = () => {
    this.setState({userLoggedIn: true});
  }

  const getView = () => {
    return this.state.userLoggedIn ? <Home /> :  <Login onLogin={this.onLogin} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <span>
          {this.getView()}
        </span>
    );
  }
}
```